# If C is a cocomplete coalgebra, then $\psi:C\rightarrow B\Omega C$ is a filtered quasi-isomorphism

Tags: homological-algebra, tensor-products, a-infinity-algebras, differential-graded-algebras

I am reading [*the PhD thesis thesis of Kenji Lefèvre-Hasegawa*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0310337.pdf) and the corresponding [*errata*](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~bernhard.keller/lefevre/TheseFinale/corrainf.pdf) by Bernhard Keller, my question is about the first error found in the thesis. **Lemma 1.3.2.3 c** states 'the adjunction morphism $\psi:C\rightarrow B\Omega C$ is a filtered quasi-isomorphism' (C is endowed with the primitive filtration).  Along the way of the proof it is claimed that the
comultiplication on $\mathrm{Gr}C$ vanishes, and this is wrong.
If we denote $W=\mathrm{Gr}(S^{-1}C)$, the thesis claims

> $\mathrm{Gr}(B\Omega C)\xrightarrow{\backsim} B\Omega(\mathrm{Gr} C)$ is the sum of complexes $V_{i}=\displaystyle\bigoplus_{i_{1}+\cdots+i_{k}=i}{SW^{\otimes i_{1}}}\otimes\dots {SW^{\otimes i_{k}}}$

Are $\mathrm{Gr}(B\Omega C)$ and  $B\Omega(\mathrm{Gr} C)$ indeed isomorphic?. If so, can anybody please give some details of such isomorphism?. I think it is consequence of the erroneous assupmtion on $\mathrm{Gr} C$, but I am not sure.

On the other hand, Keller's correction of the original proof uses a **decreasing** filtration on $B\Omega C$ named $F^{'}_{l}$, by describing

> $F^{'}_{l}$ is generated by all $m$th tensor powers of $C$ where $m\geq l$

I find the description of $F^{'}_{l}$ clear enough but I do not know how decreasing filtrations work (may they induce isomorphism in homology?). I would really appreciate some clues about these inquiries and a short clarification of what is either rescued or discarded from the original proof, in the corrected proof.

Comment: You could look at the discussion on p. 26 onwards in http://arxiv.org/abs/1904.03585v2

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathrm{Gr}(B\Omega C)\xrightarrow{\backsim} B\Omega(\mathrm{Gr} C)$ actually means they both are not isomorphic but there is a canonical quasi-isomorphism from  $\mathrm{Gr}(B\Omega C)$ to $B\Omega(\mathrm{Gr} C)$, I may conclude a similar statement from an argument of spectral sequences, see [*A primer on spectral sequences*](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/MISC/SpecSeqPrimer.pdf), example 4.3 (a homomorphism $B\Omega(\mathrm{Gr}C)\rightarrow \mathrm{Gr}(B\Omega C)$ that induces an isomorphism in homology). I have no idea about an homomorphism in the opposite direction.